# Manga/Webtoon about a plague that turns people into mindless, aggressive zombies

Tags: story-identification, manga

I believe this manga was either Korean or Japanese. The main character was a high school boy who could not feel emotion at all. He barely talked and was bullied by all but one girl who tried to protect him. Another character is the daughter of a government official or maybe even the leader of the country.

The manga starts at their school when people suddenly start "turning" and attacking/killing others. A small group of students (including main characters) escape to the roof but start "turning" there, too. The story follows the small group of survivors from this school as they try to get home and check on their families. Along the way the main character realizes he is beginning to feel emotions and doesn't know how to handle them.

I didn't finish this one, unfortunately. The last I remember the MCs are in a church that seems shady but they don't really have anywhere to go. Hope someone can help, I've been looking for this one for over a year!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.   Where and when did you read this?

Comment: Was it in color or black and white?